# node.js: How to include external .js from another server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to include .js files that are located on another server into my node.js program. Is this possible?

I can´t use `require('./local_file.js')` and get something over the Internet like this: `require('http://www.server.com/path/file.js');`

I´ve tried to make a http.request and then use eval(), but the scope is all wrong and the functions inside the external file remain undefined:

```
var source_string = load_contents_via_http('http://www.server.com/folder/file.js');
var source_string += '\n run_my_function();';
eval(source_string);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Edit (Solution): 
I solved my problem by repacking the essential parts into the script that runs on my local server, as mentioned by @zackehh. Then I used http.request to load and eval specific parts from the remote server when needed. Since the most important code was running on the server locally, the imported extra code was easier to add.

Here is a example on how I solved the problem:

```
var EssentialObject = {};
EssentialObject.ServerFunctions = {};
EssentialObject.ServerFunctions.Init = function (){
  var external_code = load_contents_via_http('http://www.server.com/file.js');
  var eval_this = external_code.substr(
    external_code.indexOf('EssentialObject.Addons = {}'),
    external_code.indexOf('// End of EssentialObject.Addons')-external_code.indexOf('EssentialObject.Addons = {}')
  );
  eval ( eval_this );
  eval ( "EssentialObject.Addons.test=true; console.log('Eval Done')" ); // Check if it works
};
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Disclaimer: this technically isn't an answer to the question, I feel it should be classed as one, as it moves towards a solution to the problem.

You *could* do it with a simple [http request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback), but I don't recommend it. You would be better off repacking the things you need on both servers in [npm](http://npmjs.com) modules and requiring them in. This allows you share your code pretty painlessly. If you don't want your code public, npm also has new [private module](https://www.npmjs.com/private-modules) options.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer since the problem in my case was more about how to approach it, and as you pointed out, repacking was a better way to go. Will edit my post with how I got it to work if anybody else is having a similar problem.

Comment: Please show how to do it via http request so it is an answer and an alternative. Thanks!